# 502 Error when edit some users

Tags: users, errors

When trying to edit a user, error 502 appears. An error appears when editing a some part of users, but I do not see patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your server is running out of resources. It happens randomly. I would recommend you contact the hosting provider and show them that error. Also ask them to increase the PHP memory limit on your server and look into the server error log files.
The 502 error is too generic, it can mean anything and your hosting provider will know what it means once they look into the server error log files.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable DEBUG ( inside wp-config.php )

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and paste here any errors you see ( on browser or error_log_php )